# MAATWEBSITE LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, maatwebsite-excel, excel-import

I want to import data tables(multiple) using excel(single) file. I am not sure how to achieve same with query builder. I am not using model for this.

Excel::import(**QUERY BUILDER INSERT QUERY**, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));

can i use insert query here? if yes then how.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They've documented that on their website:
Please see this Page.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html

Comment: thanks but i am looking for something like this: $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath(); $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get(); if(!empty($data) && $data->count()) { foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) { $insert[] = ['title' => $value['title'],'headerimage' => $value['headerimage']]; if(!empty($insert)) { $id=DB::table('question') ->insertGetId($insert); } $insert1[] = [ 'fee' => $value['fee'], 'CourseId' => $id, 'startdate' => $value['startdate'], 'enddate' => $value['enddate'] ]; if(!empty($insert1)) { $id=DB::table('question') ->insertGetId($insert); } } }